# With a DetailsView, some columns are key columns. How do I hide these columns?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Suppose I have a DetailsView, which is bound to a SQLDataSource.  The underlying table has two columns, an ID and a value.

When in display mode, I want to display only the value.  When I switch the DetailsView to edit mode, I want the user to edit the value, and not see or edit the ID.  Making the ID column not visible solves this, EXCEPT that then the ID value is not stored in the DetailsView so two-way binding does not work, and I can't update the corresponding DB record.

How do I do two-way data binding with a DetailsView, but hide the ID column from the user?

Answer (score 0):

Either use the templatefield to display a label in both modes, or I think the column as a readonly property.  Either will work.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is

1. Put the data items that are the key values into the DataKeyNames property of the DetailsView.
2. Create a template column for the first data item that is editable.  Within the template column, add asp:HiddenField controls, and set the value of the hiddenfield to the value of the key item:

   `<asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("OwnerId") %>'  />`

Comment: Just DataKeyNames are sufficient so you don't need the HiddenField.